# Filter Or Hide Row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, autofilter

**[Back story]**
I have a Google Sheet I use for emailing schedules to subcontractors. Each subcontractor has their own sheet, and I also have one last sheet called MasterSchedule.

The master schedule uses references to all the individual sheets such that all subcontractor schedules are visible. This is reaaaaaal long though. So I included a helper column in all sheets that simply returns **true** or **false** indicating whether a row should be displayed or not on the master.

However the row is still displayed on the master, but the helper column just happens to say false. So I used the AutoFilter to Hide it.

### **TLDR:**

Problem: Google Apps Script doesn't have API for the auto-Filter. Like VBA using criteria etc. So The only option I see is to hide rows. But this is very slow. I know the idea is to reduce the number of calls to the Google services, and Google suggests making an array then excuting a call on the array. I have no idea how to do this.

I need an efficient script/function to look at a column and every cell that reads **false**, the function will hide the entire row, and show all other rows.

The fastest non script method is to use Google Sheets version of auto-filter and simply un-check **false**.

I tried making a for loop that reads each cell in a column and per iteration hides the row if the cell value is false. **It is incredibly slow.**

See:

```
function MasterFilter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

  //show all the rows
  sheet.showRows(1, maxRows);

  //get data from column B
  var data = sheet.getRange('B:B').getValues();

  //iterate over all rows
  for(var i=5; i< data.length; i++){
    if(sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue() == false){
      sheet.hideRow(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change one line of your original code, to get it to work:

```
  sheet.hideRow(sheet.getRange(i,2));  // Operates on a range
```

With that, I timed it on a test spreadsheet, ~200 rows with an even distribution of `true` / `false` cells. The execution transcript reported `[4.656 seconds total runtime]`.

As you suspected, you can reduce the Service calls by using an array with a set of data (in this case, all of column B). Here's the "hide" method, using an array for testing visibility:

```
function MasterFilter() {
  var headers = 4; // # rows to skip
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

  //show all the rows
  sheet.showRows(1, maxRows);

  //get data from column B
  var data = sheet.getRange('B:B').getValues();

  //iterate over all rows
  for(var i=headers; i< data.length; i++){
    if(data[i][0] == false){
      sheet.hideRow(sheet.getRange(i+1,1));
    }
  }
}
```

According to the execution transcript, this took `[0.106 seconds total runtime]` for the test sheet. Watching the screen, it looked like 3 or 4 seconds by the time it refreshed.

Here's another way to do it. In this one, we read all the data on the Master Sheet, then use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to reduce the two-dimensional array to just the rows with `true` in column B. This smaller set is then written to the Master Sheet, after we clear all previous contents. This cut the execution time in half, `[0.059 seconds total runtime]` according to the execution transcript. Once again, delays in the refresh of the viewed copy made it look like a couple of seconds.

```
// Evaluation function for Array.filter()
function isVisible(row) {
  return (row[1] === true);  // Check column B
}

function MasterFilter2() {
  var headers = 4; // # rows to skip
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headerData = data.splice(0,headers); // Skip header rows
  var filteredData = data.filter( isVisible );
  var outputData = headerData.concat(filteredData);  // Put headers back

  sheet.clearContents();  // Clear content, keep format

  // Save filtered values
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, outputData.length, outputData[0].length).setValues(outputData); 
}
```

Comment: Hey Mogsdad,

Here is a copy w/ names changed for privacy-sake:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqHXMKHljcfYdDRzd1dpWFM3c1hjX002QlZYaHk5R2c&usp=sharing

Master2() That takes advantage of using arrays, is lightning fast, but it seems like it skips some true-rows.
 ●It also 'pastes' on top of the formulas that brought that data from the other sheets in the first place (not a big problem if I just have Master2() set Values too an additional sheet.)

Am I going about all this in a convoluted way? Should gscript be taking care of bringing the data for the "Master" in the first place?

Comment: Re Skipping; I put a breakpoint at line 51, there were 69 rows in `filteredData` and the same number of 'true' on the spreadsheet - so that seems complete. Re formulas - you didn't mention those originally, and they do change things. Certainly, if we `clear()` and `setValues()`, all formulas will be blown away. If you need to keep them, then use `MasterFilter()`, it's still much faster than what you had, and will preserve formulas & formatting. I like the last idea though - you could pull filtered versions of data from each contractor's sheet, and `append()` them to build the master.