# Hide Rows Formula in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Is there a formula on spreadsheet that will remove the rows if the value of the cell is empty? For example `=if(A2 = "","hide row A1", "show A1")`. I am using Google Form and Form Publisher addons to generate new spreadsheet base on the value that I have inputted on my forms.

Or is there any way to do this?

Generated PDF

[image]

Comment: A formula cannot change any aspect of the UI. It returns a value (or values). You could return a true/false value and use this as the basis to filter rows, but you can also just filter rows with an empty cell.

Comment: Thanks @AndyG do you have any ways to do this? because everytime I submit a form it will generate new spreadsheet or pdf.

Comment: To do what? Filter rows? I'm sure you can discover that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas are just Custom Functions return value(s), you need to solve that with Script or hide it manually.

Check that may help you

- [Hide Row in Google Sheets if Cell Contains "no" - Multiple Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972799/hide-row-in-google-sheets-if-cell-contains-no-multiple-sheets)
- [Filter Or Hide Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707027/filter-or-hide-row)

Comment: I also tried to create a script for that but the plugin is generating new spreadsheet and pulling data to master spreadsheet. Can the script will run on the new spreadsheet generated?

Answer (score 0):

Formulas just return a value or an array of values, they can't hide/show rows. You could use FILTER, QUERY among other combined Google Sheets functions to return just the need values.

Another alternate is the use of [Google Apps Script](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the row but can make its contents invisible. Use conditional formatting to change font color of entire row to 'white'